# Define a '<<' method for an attribute on an ActiveRecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got an active record object that has custom accessors for storing arrays as comma separated text.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :object_list

  def objects
    self.object_list.split(",") rescue []
  end

  def objects=(input)
   self.object_list = input.join(',')
  end
end
```

I'd like to add the following

```
def objects<<(input)
  unless self.object_list == nil
    self.object_list << ",#{input}"
  else
    self.object_list = "#{input}"
  end
end
```

So that I can do things like

```
thing.objects << 'this'
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Also avoid using `else` with `unless`, it makes it hard to read for most people! You could just for `if self.object_list` here

Comment: I tried it, it freaks out on the << in the method name

Comment: You might want to add that this is used like a real-value bit-mask with the intention that the form will use multiple check box fields named like "objects[]", one per value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def objects
    @objects ||= read_attribute(:objects).split(',')
  end

  def objects=(input)
    @objects=input
    write_attribute(:objects, @objects.join(','))
  end
end
```

That should allow you to treat objects like an array but have it save as a comma separated list in the db.

See [Overwriting Default Accessors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) in the Rails API.

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than the one I proposed, Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you like it.

Comment: Oh, @biagidp, after thinking about it, if you have a `objects` and `objects=` method there's no need to call `attr_accessor` at all, you're just overwriting it. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: this would do as long as the attributes will not look like this: "1999","Chevy","Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""","","5000.0000" (containing separator) from http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-csv-comma-delimited-of-errors/

Comment: ^^ Agreed, you'll have to handle escaping etc. if necessary, and you're going to need to make sure that you're not exceeding the limits of the datatype, for instance the length of a string if this is a string field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your << method, but why not user serialization?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by using define_method as outlined below

```
define_method("objects<<"){|input|
  unless self.object_list == nil
    self.object_list << ",#{input}"
  else
    self.object_list = "#{input}"
  end
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to leave a space, as he did in the example, if you do it this way. Ie, this won't work: `objects << 'item'`, only this `objects<< 'item'`